# Concat to field after query

Tags: mysql

If I do this

```
Select kindOfAnimal from animal_table
group by kindOfAnimal
```

I get cat, dog, cow

How can I change query that I get cat1, dog1, cow1. How to concat to value without change in table?

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT(kindOfAnimal, '1') …` …?

Comment: where is your tables ? what is cat1 ,dog1, cow1 ? your question is unclear

Comment: BTW: Whenever you need something1, something2 etc. be sure that your code/database design is not good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select CONCAT(kindOfAnimal, '1')
from animal_table
group by kindOfAnimal;
```

This works?